# MySQL JSON column prepend object

Tags: mysql, json

I want prepend object in MYSQL JSON column.

My actual value on JSON column:

```
{"owner": {"type": "radio", "label": "Test"}}
```

What I want:

```
{"initial": {"complex_object": "here"}, "owner": {"type": "radio", "label": "Test"}}
```

My MySQL request to generate JSON object.

```
JSON_OBJECT('initial', JSON_OBJECT('label', 'text radio', 'type', 'radio', 'display', 'inline', 'prefill', false, 'choices', JSON_OBJECT('true', 'Oui', 'false', 'Non'), 'accepted_values', JSON_ARRAY('true')))
```

What I would like to do is add this new object to the beginning of the already existing string.

MySQL JSON does not work as I want with **JSON_ARRAY_APPEND** because it's not an array, and I do not want an array.

**JSON_SET** reorder the order of the keys of the object, and it is necessary to respect the order that I want me.

An idea ?

Comment: Why do you need the keys in a specific order?

Comment: Because in our project, we want to display the different fields in a specific order.

We do not want to change the code, so we have to adapt to our MySQL column.

Comment: If you desire idempotent data then you CAN NOT use the JSON datatype.  The JSON datatype 'organizes' your data for faster searching and the side effect is that it will alphabetize your keys.  This means you will have to use some sort of text datatype and re-write the entire column to do the pre-pending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{"initial": {"complex_object": "here"}, "owner": {"type": "radio", "label": "Test"}}
so the first part of json value is it static

Comment: what does this mean?(